# SAT Grammar question. Writing part

Tags: grammar

This question is from College Board SAT book.(see the text below) The explanation of the answer seems a little bit strange to me. Because it says : the simple present verb “remark” is the appropriate verb
tense in this context. But,  "visitor" is a third person. So, shouldn't it have been "remarks"??? Or, shouldn't it have been in the past simple?
I'd appreciate any help.

> As I walked through the exhibit, I overheard a
>    VISITOR'S REMARK, “You know, that grandfather clock
>   actually runs. Its glass door swings open, and the clock
>   can be wound up.”
>
> A) NO CHANGE
>    B) visitors remarking
>    C) visitor remarked
>    D) visitor remark
>
> QUESTION 20.
>   Choice D is the best answer because the article “a” requires the singular
>   noun “visitor,” and the simple present verb “remark” is the appropriate verb
>   tense in this context.
>   Choices A, B, and C are incorrect because each contains either a noun or
>   verb that does not fit the context.

Comment: Jacquet, the correct answer is D. So, there is no possessive and book asserts that "remark" is verb. ( I agree with your answer)

Comment: Sorry, I should read the whole thing before commenting (I've deleted my incorrect comment). I'd stopped at ‘remark’. Since it’s followed by a comma and then direct speech, _remark_ has to be a verb, not a noun, so the book is correct: D is the only correct answer. “I heard a visitor remarking” would also be correct, but that's not one of the options.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The answer is correct, but the explanation is wrong: the clausal complement is not headed by a finite ("simple present") verb but by an **unmarked infinitive**--which is why it is not inflected to agree with its 3d person singular subject or to fix the tense of the event.

Comment: @StoneyB That's why it's unmarked, yes; my first comment was to the effect that it was correct the way it was, since _remark_ was a noun rather than a verb here. Once I read the rest of the sentence, it was clear that that was obviously not an option. I didn't think pivotal constructions were necessary in a comment (that would have made it an answer instead). But you're right, their explanation of _why_ D is correct is doubly wrong, both by calling _remark_ here a “simple present verb” and calling it a tense to begin with.

Comment: Thanks very much! But I reckon that unmarked infinitives is not so common in these type of sentences. ( I mean with the third person) I know it is common to say sentences like that " She lets him go (not "goes') But in my case it seems smth rare.

Comment: @Kamran Unmarked infinitival clause complements are unremarkable with some very common verbs of perception (*overhear*, *see*, *feel*, *notice*, *watch*) and causation (*have*, *let*, *make*), and sometimes *know* and *help*.

Answer (score 3):

> **Remark**
>
> *verb* 1 [reporting verb] Say something as a comment; mention. *[with direct speech] '"Tom's looking peaky," she remarked'*
>
> *noun* 1 A written or spoken comment. *'I decided to ignore his rude remarks'*
>
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/remark)

There are two valid answers.

Answer A ("a visitor's remark") uses the word as a noun. It doesn't matter that the quoted speech contains multiple sentences - it can still be considered a single remark. The word "a" here can quantify either *visitor* or *remark*. It's ambiguous, though associating *a* with *visitor* seems stronger in the limited context given. Either way, there's no problem with singular agreement.

Answer D ("overheard a visitor remark, ...") uses the word as a verb. There's also no problem here with singular agreement.

Comment: +1 By gum, I missed A being "no change". I should know better by now than to trust test-writers to get *anything* right.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and consideration. It seems to be much more clear to me now. Thank you!

Comment: @StoneyB, I totally agree with you. It is about The Objective Infinitive Construction. I just remembered this example : " I watched her approach"